# Add fields to Elasticsearch index

Tags: python-3.x, django, elasticsearch

I'm using [django-elasticsearch-dsl](https://django-elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io) to build the elasticsearch index and I want to dynamically add fields (to the created index `cars`) that don't exist in MySQL schema

I was based on [this example](https://django-elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html#handle-relationship-with-nestedfield-objectfield) and added `Website` to illustrate what I want to achieve

```
Manufacturer ----< Car ----< Ad ----< Website
```

`----<`: One to many relationships

In this case, I can easily add `manufacturer` and `ads` NestedField/ObjectField to `cars` index because they are directly linked to `Car` table

Is there a way to add `website` object to the `cars` index, other than linking it directly to `Car` table?

When I tried to rebuild the index (`python manage.py search_index --rebuild -f`) I get the following error

> django_elasticsearch_dsl.exceptions.VariableLookupError: Failed lookup for key [website] in <Car: Car object (1)>

```
$ python manage.py search_index --rebuild -f
Deleting index '<elasticsearch_dsl.index.Index object at 0x10baeb3a0>'
Creating index '<elasticsearch_dsl.index.Index object at 0x10baeb3a0>'
Indexing 1 'Car' objects
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/git/django_es_dsl/dedsl_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/fields.py", line 52, in get_value_from_instance
    instance = instance[attr]
TypeError: 'Car' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/git/django_es_dsl/dedsl_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/fields.py", line 58, in get_value_from_instance
    instance = getattr(instance, attr)
AttributeError: 'Car' object has no attribute 'website'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/git/django_es_dsl/dedsl_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/fields.py", line 63, in get_value_from_instance
    instance = instance[int(attr)]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'website'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/user/git/django_es_dsl/dedsl_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/user/git/django_es_dsl/dedsl_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/user/git/django_es_dsl/dedsl_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/user/git/django_es_dsl/dedsl_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/user/git/django_es_dsl/dedsl_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/management/commands/search_index.py", line 134, in handle
    self._rebuild(models, options)
  File "/Users/user/git/django_es_dsl/dedsl_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/management/commands/search_index.py", line 115, in _rebuild
    self._populate(models, options)
  File "/Users/user/git/django_es_dsl/dedsl_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/management/commands/search_index.py", line 92, in _populate
    doc().update(qs)
  File "/Users/user/git/django_es_dsl/dedsl_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/documents.py", line 162, in update
    return self.bulk(
  File "/Users/user/git/django_es_dsl/dedsl_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/documents.py", line 123, in bulk
    return bulk(client=self._get_connection(), actions=actions, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/git/django_es_dsl/dedsl_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/actions.py", line 297, in bulk
    for ok, item in streaming_bulk(client, actions, *args, **kwargs):
  File "/Users/user/git/django_es_dsl/dedsl_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/actions.py", line 208, in streaming_bulk
    for bulk_data, bulk_actions in _chunk_actions(
  File "/Users/user/git/django_es_dsl/dedsl_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/actions.py", line 60, in _chunk_actions
    for action, data in actions:
  File "/Users/user/git/django_es_dsl/dedsl_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/documents.py", line 146, in _get_actions
    yield self._prepare_action(object_instance, action)
  File "/Users/user/git/django_es_dsl/dedsl_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/documents.py", line 132, in _prepare_action
    self.prepare(object_instance) if action != 'delete' else None
  File "/Users/user/git/django_es_dsl/dedsl_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/documents.py", line 98, in prepare
    field_value = field.get_value_from_instance(
  File "/Users/user/git/django_es_dsl/dedsl_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/fields.py", line 120, in get_value_from_instance
    objs = super(ObjectField, self).get_value_from_instance(
  File "/Users/user/git/django_es_dsl/dedsl_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/fields.py", line 68, in get_value_from_instance
    raise VariableLookupError(
django_elasticsearch_dsl.exceptions.VariableLookupError: Failed lookup for key [website] in <Car: Car object (1)>
```

Here is a minimal example of the code I used:

#### model.py

```
from django.db import models


class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey('Manufacturer', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)


class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Ad(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    url = models.URLField(null=True)
    car = models.ForeignKey('Car', related_name='ads', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Website(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    url = models.URLField(null=True)
    ad = models.ForeignKey('Ad', related_name='website', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

#### documents.py

```
from django_elasticsearch_dsl import Document, fields
from django_elasticsearch_dsl.registries import registry
from elasticsearch_dsl import analyzer

from .models import Car, Manufacturer, Ad, Website


@registry.register_document
class CarDocument(Document):
    manufacturer = fields.ObjectField(properties={
        'name': fields.TextField(),
    })
    ads = fields.NestedField(properties={
        'title': fields.TextField(),
        'pk': fields.IntegerField(),
    })
    website = fields.ObjectField(properties={
        'name': fields.TextField(),
    })

    class Index:
        name = 'cars'

    class Django:
        model = Car
        fields = [
            'name',
        ]
        related_models = [Manufacturer, Ad]


# Adding the data
m = Manufacturer(
    id=1,
    name='manuf1',
)
m.save()

car = Car(
    id=1,
    name="Car one",
    manufacturer=m
)
car.save()

ad = Ad(
    id=1,
    title='Ads title',
    url='https://www.example.com/ads-url-goes-here',
    car=car
)
ad.save()

ws = Website(
    id=1,
    name='Ads Website',
    url='https://www.example.com',
    ad=ad
)
ws.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

`object is not subscriptable` means there's no `__getitem__()` method available for what django-elasticsearch-dsl is using to populate the document fields (in this case, a Django model)

I think you are better off adding `prepare_ads` and `prepare_website` methods to populate those `CarDocument` fields.

```py
def prepare_ads(self, instance):
    return [{'pk': ad.pk, 'title': ad.title}
            for ad in instance.ads]
```